# Calling copy constructor from an unknown class without new

Tags: c++, constructor, reinterpret-cast

Here is the deal:

I have a templated class C

```
template<class T>
class C;
```

that has a member that is basically a pointer to a reinterpretation of T called P (don't worry about P)

```
P* reint;
```

what I want to do is a method that receives a T and copies it into reint

```
void foo (T& param) {
    new (reint) (param);
}
```

problem is the compiler is giving out warnings that reint is not a T that I want to get rid of. My first idea was to reinterpret reint into a T:

```
void foo (T& param) {
    new (reinterpret_cast<T&>(*reint)) T(param);
}
```

but the compiler started giving me an error saying

```
invalid conversion from const void* to void*
```

So i looked it up and new is defined as such:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();
```

So for some reason my casting is turning reint into a const void*.

New idea: cast reint to a T and call the copy constructor. Problem: no clue how to call the copy constructor from an unknown class.

(maybe

```
reinterpret_cast<T>(*reint).T(param);
```

?)

Could you help me please?

Comment: You're casting to a reference, while placement-new wants a pointer. Did you mean `reinterpret_cast<T*>(reint)`?

Comment: That might work. I was also trying to make a new T from param and casting into P to put it in reint.

Comment: Why not `reinterpret_cast<T&>(*reint) = param;`?

Comment: because T doesn't necessarily have a = operator.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like:

```
#include <stdexcept>

struct Data
{
    const std::string value;
    Data(const std::string& value)
    :   value(value)
    {}
    Data(const Data& other) = default;
    Data& operator = (const Data& other) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
class Holder
{
    public:
    Holder() = default;
    Holder(const T& data) {
        assign(data);
    }
    ~Holder() {
        release();
    }

    void assign(const T& data) {
        release();
        new (m_data) T(data);
        m_valid = true;
    }

    void release() {
        if(m_valid) {
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data)->~T();
            m_valid = false;
        }
    }

    const T& get() const {
        if( ! m_valid) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid");
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_data);
    }

    private:
    bool m_valid = false;
    char m_data[sizeof(T)];
};


#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Holder<Data> holder;
    holder.assign(Data("Hello"));
    const Data& data = holder.get();
    std::cout << data.value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes but what I want is to get rid of the compiler warning that says that m_data is not a T

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho There should be none - the (char) buffer m_data is passed to the placement new as pointer

Comment: Except that you are trying to initialize m_valid   ....  error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘m_valid’

Comment: @DieterLücking am talking about in-class initialization of m_valid? I know =default and =delete are C++11. Is in-class initialization of non-static member variables supported in C++11? No?

Comment: @Kedar Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement

Comment: The warning was because I was used a const T.

Answer (score 0):

You're going the *wrong* way, you want somethng more like:

```
reint = reinterpret_cast<P*>(param);
```

Comment: If i do that the copy constructor for T won't be called. If there are any alloc'd objects the pointers will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make a struct to return the reinterpreted P for both const and unconst

```
template <class T> struct Temp {
    T* switch (P* r) { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(r); }
}

template <class T> struct Temp <const T> {
    T* switch (P* r) { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(r); }
}
```

then use the struct to remove const from reint

```
new (Temp::switch(reint)) T(param);
```